# Infinite scrolling with jQuery not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code works on desktop but not on mobile devices:

```
var page = 2;
var enableScroll = true;
var $container = $('.main-panel');
$container.scroll(function(e) {
  if (enableScroll === true && $container.scrollTop() === $container.prop('scrollHeight') - $container.height()) {
    $.get("/usuario/conversacion/mensajes-next/?pagina=" + page + "&con=" + $("#id_conversacion").val()).done(function(data){
        if(data == ''){
            enableScroll = false;
        }else{
            $('.timeline li:last').after(data);
            page = page + 1;
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr){
        showPop("Se ha producido un error al cargar las agresiones. Por favor, int&eacute;ntelo de nuevo", "error");
    });
  }
})
```

The scroll event `$container.scroll(function(e) {` does not work on mobile,
it works with `$container.on({'touchmove': function(e) {` but touchmove detects different heights.

Anyone know how to do an infinitescroll in any device?

Comment: Have you tried with window.scroll event?

Comment: window.scroll does not work on mobile